# How to replace useEffect with dependencies

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I am working on a simple memory game app and I am wondering if there is a way how to not use an useEffect hook with dependencies in the following case:

I have a function which is called after user clicks on the card. It saves the clicked card to one of two state variables, that will be compared later.

```
const handleClick = (card: Card) => {
if (card.id !== choiceOne?.id) {
  if (choiceOne) return setChoiceTwo(card)
  return setChoiceOne(card)
}
  }
```

And when choiceTwo is updated, useEffect is called and do the card comparison and other necessary actions:

```
  const useAsyncUseEffect = (fn: () => void, depends: Parameters<typeof useEffect>[1]) => {
    useEffect(() => {
      fn()
    }, [depends])
  }

  useAsyncUseEffect(async () => {
    if (choiceOne && choiceTwo) {
      setDisabled(true)
      if (choiceOne.src === choiceTwo.src) {
        setMatchCount(prev => prev + 1)
        setCards(prev =>
          prev.map(card => (card.src === choiceOne.src ? { ...card, match: true } : card))
        )
        resetSelection()
      } else {
        await sleep(1000)
        resetSelection()
      }
    }
  }, [choiceTwo])
```

Comment: 1: What do you mean "how to not use a useEffect hook with dependencies"? It's clearly required if you want to retain the same behavior. 2: I think `useAsyncEffect` is a catchier name than `useAsyncUseEffect`.

Comment: @kelly I am trying to find another way how to do it, because I want to avoid event driven architecture in my app(s). Of course, it is kind of unecessary in this simple app, but I want find a solution to that. 2: thank you :) I didn't realize that, it was just regular useEffect at first which I refactored.

Comment: How is an app supposed to be useful if it can't be driven by events?

Comment: I probably didn't explain this correctly. Using many useEffects with dependencies in the app can make reading of the code really difficult. Change of one variable can trigger many unpredictable actions which are hidden somewhere in the code. Imagine you are preparing a meal and the first three steps are on page 5 in the book, but fourth step is on page 25.

Comment: Well, how else would you know when to run the effect when something changes? Maybe it's a matter of code organization than it is the problem of having dependencies in useEffect.